# Can I set a function to use different variables depending on how it’s triggered?

Tags: javascript, variables

I’m making a page to track the quantity/value of 8 sets of assets.

Each Asset will have several buttons that do the same thing just for different Variables depending on the asset that triggers them.

I’m wondering if there is a way to set the variables when it’s triggered or do O just have to copy-paste and edit each function 8 times?

Here is the code I’m starting with it adds A quantity of the asset and removes the cost from the cash value

```
function buya() {
  var quant = document.getElementById("input").value;
  quant = Number(quant)
  var cost = document.getElementById("a3").innerHTML;
  var cash = document.getElementById("cash").innerHTML;
  cash = Number(cash) 
  cost = Number(cost)
  var a4 = document.getElementById("a4").innerHTML;
  a4 = Number(a4) 
  console.log(a4) 
  console.log(quant)
  if (cash > cost) {
    cash = cash - cost;
    a4 += quant;
    document.getElementById("cash").innerHTML = cash;
    document.getElementById("a4").innerHTML = a4;
  } else 
    alert("you don't have enough money to buy those shares")
}
```

Basically I want to swap most all of the variables a3, a4 into b2,b4 variables

——edit—— Okay I think I have a fix but it’s clumsy and better ones would be appreciated.
First Add a drop-down to select which asset then replace the things I want to shift with blank variables m, say cuz then at the start of the function add an 8 pronged if/else statement assigning field locations to those variables based on the drop-down selection.

Hate it when the answer pops into my head 5 minutes after posting
——edit ends——

Comment: You're looking for closures.

Comment: Give the function parameters for the values that can vary.

Answer (score 0):

Use function parameters, and then bind event listeners to functions that call it with different parameters.

```js
function buya(costid, a4id) {
  var quant = document.getElementById("input").value;
  quant = Number(quant)
  var cost = document.getElementById(costid).innerHTML;
  var cash = document.getElementById("cash").innerHTML;
  cash = Number(cash) 
  cost = Number(cost)
  var a4 = document.getElementById(a4id).innerHTML;
  a4 = Number(a4) 
  console.log(a4) 
  console.log(quant)
  if (cash > cost) {
    cash = cash - cost;
    a4 += quant;
    document.getElementById("cash").innerHTML = cash;
    document.getElementById(a4id).innerHTML = a4;
  } else 
    alert("you don't have enough money to buy those shares")
}

someElement.addEventListener("click", () => buya("a3", "a4"));
otherElement.addEventListener("click", () => buya("b2", "b4"));
```

Answer (score 0):

We can pass elements as parameters to the function

```js
function buya(ele1, ele2){
      console.log(ele1.innerHTML);
      console.log(ele2.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<div id="a3">I am a3</div>
<div id="a4">I am a4</div>
<div id="b3">I am b3</div>
<div id="b4">I am b4</div>

<button onClick="buya(document.getElementById('a3'), document.getElementById('a4'));">Click for A3 and A4</button>

<button onClick="buya(document.getElementById('b3'), document.getElementById('b4'));">Click for B3, B4</button>
```